# How can I define multiple options for UIViewAnimation?

Tags: iphone, uiviewanimation

Probably it is just a question of proper syntax.

I use the `animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:` UIView method.

The `options:` is the problematic part here: when I assign **only one option** (for example *UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut*) everything works fine.

What if I want to assign **multiple options** to the same animation? How can I do that?

I have tried the following code, but the `options:` part turned out to be completely **ignored**:

```
>   [UIView animateWithDuration:DURATION
>                         delay:DELAY
>                       options:(UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction,
>                                UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut)
>                    animations: ^{/*animations here*/}
>                    completion: ^(BOOL finished){/*actions on complete*/}];
```

It was just a try and it didn't work. Which syntax should I use here?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

**Objective-C**

```
options:(UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction |
                            UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut)
```

**Swift**

In Swift UIViewAnimationOptions is an [Option set type](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/optionset) and multiple options can be passed following way:

```
options:[.AllowUserInteraction, .CurveEaseInOut]
```

Comment: I was sure it will be easy. Thank you, Vladimir. 
Спасибо.

Comment: What's the answer for Swift?  It doesn't like the '|' operator apparently.

Comment: Why do they use, what i see as the "OR" operator? What is the history behind this?

Comment: @nickcarraway, not sure I understand the question. Every UIViewAnimationOptions value is a bit flag, i.e. it has exactly one bit set to 1 in its binary representation. Result of `|` (bitwise OR) operator will be a number that has bits set for every option passed to it.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add the reason it seems the compiler ignored your supplied options yet didn't throw an error is because the syntax that you tried makes use of the comma operator which is often overlooked in C. Essentially

```
(UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction, UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut)
```

tels the compiler to discard the first option and only assign the value after the comma. In the more general case, the first argument to the comma operator is evaluated, but it's result is discarded.